# new keyword vs creating instances

Tags: php, oop, instantiation

On some opensource codes, why do they make use of:

```
$router = Cfw_Router::getInstance();
```

Instead of just using

```
$rounter = new Cfw_Router();
```

Does it have advantages?

---

`getInstance()`:

```
public static function getInstance() {
    if (null === self::$__instance) {
        self::$__instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$__instance;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're making use of the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).  Basically, it allows only one instance to exist at any given time. However, it can sometimes be used to provide a global variable, which is not always the best thing in a design (see the criticisms in the link above).

Answer (score 4):

The first use is called a [`singleton`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). It ensures that only one instance of the object exists.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the singleton pattern. With getInstance, only 1 instance of the object will be created in the whole program, while with new, a new object instance is created in each call.
That can be useful for example in a database handling object. You don't want to have multiple object instances in your program (and multiple connections) but instead you want only one instance of database handler and connection across all your program.